# Execute GUI programs as root without password

Tags: sudo, kde, root, authentication

I know that in order to execute a CLI program using sudo, but without the need to typing your password, all you need to do is put

```
user ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/program
```

in /etc/sudoers, or even better in a file in /etc/sudoers.d.
I've tried that and it works without any problem.

However, for GUI application it's different. 
If I try, for example, to put

```
user ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/gparted
```

in the same file, when GParted starts the usual GUI password prompt still comes up.

Is there a way to obtain the same result for GUI applications? I don't know if it's something that depends on the particular Desktop Environment, but I suspect it does, given that each of them probably uses a different tool to display the prompt.

In my specific scenario, I'm using Kubuntu 18.04, so I suppose the question applies to all KDE distros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same. But remember to run the program you need to do `sudo program`. Therefore if a launcher is launching the program, you need to direct the launcher to an executable wrapper that contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo «program»
```

Comment: I created a bash script wrapper like you said, and modified the KDE menu entry to point at my script instead of the program directly.

It worked like a charm! Thank you very much!

I will mark your answer as correct!

Comment: Now I am wondering, how did it prompt you for the password?

Comment: It didn't prompt me at all. The program started directly:)

Comment: Sorry I just noticed/remembered you have an `/etc/sudoers` to stop it asking for a password.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the accepted answer, which works perfectly, I'd like to add that in my specific case (on KDE), I don't even need to create an executable script and direct the field "command" in the menu entry to that script.

I can directly type "sudo program" in the "command" field of the menu entry, which is very handy!